# Troubleshooting Zapier Webhook POSTING to Flask Server

Tags: python, flask, zapier

I am trying to use my Flask server to receive webhooks in a POST from a Zap, but I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I test.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
TypeError: receive_webhook() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Here is my handler for the webhook:

```
@app.route("/webhook", methods=['POST'])
def receive_webhook(request):
    print(request.json)

    return request.json
```

Here's a screenshot of my Zap I am trying to send the POST from[image: Zap Screenshot]
Thanks for any assistance.

It seems like Zapier is calling my handler with no argument. Shouldn’t it be passing the payload as that `request` argument or am I misunderstanding something here?

Edit: Also, if it's relevant, I'm using Nginx and Gunicorn for hosting. On an Ubuntu Linode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was using the Flask request module incorrectly. This code made it work -

```
@app.route("/webhook", methods=['POST'])
def receive_webhook():
    print(request.data)
    return request.data
```